# How do I add values to a threadlocal List

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-local

I have a threadLocal list `ThreadLocal<List<int>> numbers`. But I want to be able to add values to this list and use other methods like Contains(). How can I do this and make sure the list is local to the thread?

Comment: You can access it `numbers.Value` to access the list, `numbers` will always remain Thread Local by design

Comment: Thank you very much